# How do I break for loop and retake screenshot after pixel is clicked?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to click on a certain colored pixel when it appears in a defined screenshot and then retake the screenshot and scan for more certain colored pixels and click one once it finds one and so on. I think my code is taking the screen shot and then scanning the pixels for the color and once it finds the color it clicks it, but it doesn't retake a screenshot, instead, it continues to scan that screenshot for more pixels with matching color and clicking them. How do I break the for loop that scans the pixels once one is found and clicked and then start the process over at retaking the screenshot? My code is below, thank you!

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

time.sleep(2)

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

#Color of enemy: (254, 118, 136)

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:

    range1 = 250
    range2 = 258
    range3 = 114
    range4 = 125
    range5 = 122
    range6 = 148
    
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot()
    width, height = pic.size
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(((0.5*width)-100),(0.5*height-100),200,200))
    width, height = pic.size
    
    for x in range(0,width,1):
        for y in range(0,height,1):

            r,g,b = pic.getpixel((x,y))

            if (((r in range(range1,range2))and(g in range(range3,range4)))):
                #and(b in range(range5,range6)))):
                moveTo(x+width,y+height)
                click(x+width,y+height)
                time.sleep(0.1)
                break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer but your issue is the break is only getting out of the first loop over y and not the one over x. One solution to this is to make a function for your looping and return out of the function

Comment: I added in  `if (mouseClicked == 1): break` after the first for loop and it seems to have fixed the issue